# Find the 10 largest quantity lines in a text file with shipment ID , UPC code , quantity

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, heap

It is an interview question.

Given a text file, each line includes  :   shipment ID ,   UPC  code ,  quantity

Find the 10 largest quantity lines.

My solutions :

By c++

make a min heap (with size 10) with quantity as compare object.

Read each entry as a struct with field { shipment ID, UPC code, quantity }

Compare it with the top element of the 10-element min-heap,

if > replace the top element with it,  else read the next element.

It is O(n lg n).

Space O(1).

Better solutions ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side note: Your time cost is actually O(n), since the per-element insertion time is a constant (O(log 10)).

The basic idea is sound — you won't do better than O(n) in terms of cost — but rather than rolling your own heap, use `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: @user1002288: I've amended my answer.

Comment: @user1002288 O(n) is linear..?

Comment: @jli: Is that a question or a statement? In any event, the OP probably wrote the comment before seeing my amended answer.

Comment: According to the edit log (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8452571/revisions) your original answer did include the O(n) statement.

Comment: @jli: The edit log doesn't show changes made within five minutes of the original posting.